# Next / Previous button to go to & fro through objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement a to & fro through objects in Rails.

Versions:

1. Rails: 4.2.5
2. Ruby: 2.3.0

So requirement is: I have an array of ids. There are up & down buttons. If I click on down then it would navigate me to next object & vice versa. The navigation should happen from the specific object ids only from the array.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have a controller that's already giving you all the objects then this is probably a Javascript question. If not, more information is needed

Comment: It seems to be working now. Basically, the ids come from a different page. I have created 2 methods as previous & next. & keeping the ids in session. If I am coming out of this page, then the session id destroyed. The page is refreshed every-time we click on up or down buttons. But I need to do it with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed this issue with Ajax.
I kept all the ids in session. & I am checking the index every time & by queryI am going to next id & just refresh the page through Ajax.

Made 2 methods as next & previous.

```
all_next_ids = session[:ids]
index_of_current = all_next_ids.index(current_id) # current id when clicked
next_id = all_nexts[index_of_current + 1]

Then from query find the next id object
```

Same thing done for Previous.